# Existence of injection administering certification?

Tags: blood, injections, legal, medical-training, qualifiy-certify

Is there a legal training, certification, or license that allows one to legally inject substances/medications into others? Is it illegal to inject others or aid in injecting others without such certifications, licenses, or training? For example to aid someone in injecting medications in a hard to reach area or vaccines at a drive. In that case, what about drawing blood specimens for either donation purposes or testing? All situations I am asking about are with a fully informed consensual adult and with legal substances and proper procedures and materials.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is. In the USA, the certification is called a [Medical Assistant](http://www.aama-ntl.org/medical-assisting/what-is-a-medical-assistant#.WbId6bKGP5c).  It is a certification that is unlicensed, thus they must work under supervision of a licensed provider (who CAN inject legally) such as LVN RN BSN APRN PA MD/DO...

[Phlebotamy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlebotomy) (drawing blood) is different than administering injections, as you are not putting a substance in the patient.  There is a certification program for this as well, and can be done by most health practitioners.  But regarding whether it can be done by someone not certified, it seems that rules differ institution to institution.

Comment: I'm going to phone a friend to fill in if I missed something, @CareyGregory since your background is in emergency medicine - can EMTs deliver meds (beyond like an EpiPen)?  I do know they can draw labs and place IVs, but unsure about administration of meds or vaccines.